# Avoid scanning third party libraries in Veracode

Tags: veracode

We recently started using Veracode for vulnerability testing. Is there a way to selectively exclude all the third party libraries and focus the scan only on our internal libraries code?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for veracode?  What did you find?

Also wouldn't excluding libraries you have used potentially mean you get a false positive?

Comment: The documentation hasn't been helpful on this one. Also, I agree that the libraries have an impact but I want a separate insight into the vulnerabilities of our code base as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi: The answer to your question depends on the language in which the application you are scanning was written.

- Java: Veracode respects WAR file structure conventions and treats JARs in the /lib directory as third party code. They are included in Software Composition Analysis results, if you subscribe to that service, but we do not otherwise report vulnerabilities that reside in code in this directory.
- C/C++ / .NET: By default only the top level executables will be scanned. The static engine will also follow code paths from the top level executables into third party libraries if they are present, but will not check *all* possible parts of the third party libraries for flaws. You can go into Advanced Mode and click Show Dependencies if you *want* to scan all possible paths in the third party dependent libraries for flaws.
- PHP/JavaScript/Android/iOS/other languages: It's not possible to exclude third party libraries for these languages.

If you have additional questions, please contact Veracode Support and they can help you further.

Comment: Thanks Tim, our application is in .NET. I was to able to go under Show Dependencies and exclude the third party DLLs

Answer (score 1):

Veracode agent based scan is to find out vulnerabilities in all the dependency libraries including third party libs.

For JavaScript/NPM projects `scope` can be set to `production` to exclude devDependencies from the scan. Add a file named `srcclr.yml` to the root of the project add this to it:

```
# Prevent scanning 'devDependencies' for an NPM project
scope: production
```

References from Veracode:
https://docs.veracode.com/r/Multi_Language_Scan_Directives
https://docs.veracode.com/r/Veracode_SCA_Agent_Commands

> For NPM, you can set the scope directive to one of these values:
>
> ```
> production or prod to restrict the scan to production dependencies, including > the optional dependencies you can install.
> development or dev to restrict the scan to development dependencies.
> ```